# Change collation of a MySQL table to utf8_general_cs

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to change collation MySQL table to utf8_general_cs but got following error:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE 'utf8_general_cs';
ERROR 1273 (HY000): Unknown collation: 'utf8_general_cs'
```

I run "SHOW COLLATE" command and "utf8_general_cs" is not in the results.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have case-sensitive Unicode collations, because it's a difficult problem.  Some languages collate lower-case before upper-case, and others collate upper-case before lower-case.  SQL Server tries to do case-sensitive Unicode, taking locale into consideration.

You have a couple of choices:

- use collation utf8_bin (probably the easiest)
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-collation-unicode-uca.html

Comment: It's interesting how case-sensitive is a difficult problem. If you asked me to guess, I would take a shot that case-insensitive is a more difficult problem to solve. Can you elaborate on that a little?

Comment: The next sentence describes the problem. IBM has a series of pages about "language-aware collation." Case-insensitive is super easy, because it doesn't matter how the language sorts different cases.

Comment: I still don't understand. Languages sort characters by accents, not by case.